# BadRequest calling New-AzScheduledQueryRule - Action.aznsAction.actionGroup malformed from Cmdlet

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

I'm following along with the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log#managing-log-alerts-using-powershell and am running into a 400 on the call to `New-AzScheduledQueryRule`.  When I try to troubleshoot by passing a `-Debug` to the cmdlet, I see that the `action.aznsAction.actionGroup` value is definitely going to be a problem -- it's value is `[ "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSActionGroupResource" ]`.

Sure enough, the returned error from the PUT API centers on that element:

```
Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "LinkedInvalidPropertyId",
    "message": "Property id 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSActionGroupResource' at path 'properties.action.aznsAction.actionGroup[0]' is invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'."
  }
}
```

Initially, before running my script, I just have an Action Group and a `kusto` text file for my query; I create everything else via cmdlets:

- `New-AzScheduledQueryRuleSource`, passing my `kusto` content (works fine)
- `New-AzScheduleQueryRuleSchedule` (works fine)
- `New-AzScheduledQueryRuleAznsActionGroup` (pass in my existing ActionGroup name, `{}` for `-CustomWebhookPayload` - works fine)
- `New-AzScheduledQueryRuleLogMetricTrigger` (works fine)
- `New-AzScheduledQueryRuleTriggerCondition` - passing in the new MetricTrigger (works fine)
- `New-AzScheduledQueryRuleAlertingAction` - passing in the AznsActionGroup from above, plus TriggerCondition from above - works fine.

I pass this for the call:

```
New-AzScheduledQueryRule -Location eastusn -Enabled $true -Action $alertingAction -Description $Description -Schedule $schedule -Source $source -name $Rulename -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Debug
```

which is passing all the objects I've previously created. All look fine in the VS Code PS debugger.  However, the `action` JSON from the `-Debug` output looks like this, which is what seems odd to me:

```
    "action": {
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
      "severity": "1",
      "aznsAction": {
        "actionGroup": [
          "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSActionGroupResource"
        ],
        "emailSubject": "my Subject",
        "customWebhookPayload": "{}"
      },
      "throttlingInMin": 0,
      "trigger": {
        "thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
        "threshold": 1.0,
        "metricTrigger": {
          "thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 1.0,
          "metricTriggerType": "Consecutive",
          "metricColumn": "Computer"
        }
      }
    }
```

Are people having trouble, per chance, with this cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I want to accept this answer, but I did get it to work.  If you hand-hack the object output from `$alertingAction = AzScheduledQueryRuleAlertingAction`, namely by re-assigning the property `$alertingAction.AznsAction.ActionGroup[0]` to be the output of `$actionGroup Get-AzActionGroup -ResourceGroupName myRG -Name myActionGrp`, as in this block:

```
$alertingAction.AznsAction.ActionGroup[0]  = $actionGroup.Id
```

and *then* call `New-AzScheduledQueryRule`, the cmdlet works, and the ScheduledQueryRule is created properly,.

This sure feels like a bug in `New-AzScheduledQueryRule`.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same thing. I think it's possibly an issue of confusing naming, documentation, and lack of validation in the New-AzScheduledQueryRuleAznsActionGroup cmdlet.

When I first looked at it I did wonder how it would know what resourceGroup to get ther ActionGroup from. Instead of passing in just the name of ActionGroup, pass in the resourceId, which is what I think it expects but is not so clear about.

e.g.

$actionGroupResource = Get-AzActionGroup -Name $actionGroupName -ResourceGroupName $myRg
$actionGroup = New-AzScheduledQueryRuleAznsActionGroup -ActionGroup $actionGroupResource.Id

Assuming it's just the one ActionGroup you want. Then you shouldn't need to hack in the resourceId later on.